# Negative lookahead after a match

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm using this regex to check the following block of text.

`((?<=(over the)).*)?(ask.*question[s]?| answer(ing)?.*question[s]?)(?!(business))`

But I'd like to exclude this block because it has `business` in it, so I modified it to include a negative lookahead `(?!(business))`.

It should exclude this block;

> I just need to ask you a few questions to recommend the best option for you. What kind of business do you have?

It should include this block;

> I just need to ask you a few questions to recommend the best option for you.

But negative lookahead seems to not be working?

Comment: try `(?!.*(business))`

Comment: Instead of `(?!(business))` you must use `(?!.*business)` since it is not right after the match, but after 0+ other chars. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pup44J/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `(?!(business))` you may use `(?!.*business)` since the substring `business` is not right after the match, but after zero or more other chars.

Use

```
((?<=over the).*)?(ask.*questions?| answer(?:ing)?.*questions?)(?!.*business)
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pup44J/1).